# Internal Server Error on ajax GET request in Spring MVC

Tags: ajax, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Hi everyone i'm new to spring MVC so i have little idea about the framework. All I'm trying to do is refresh a div in my view with items filtered by a hibernate query, which prints correctly to standard out.

For some reason I'm not aware of I get a 500; Internal server error when i try a get request via ajax. 
I changed the return type in the controller, my original idea was to use the default index controller with an optional parameter.

View:

```
<div id="itemListContainer">
                <c:if test="${!empty items}">
                    <c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">
                        <c:url value="/showImage.htm" var="url">
                            <c:param name="id" value="${item.id}" />
                        </c:url>
                        <div id="${item.id}" class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-xs-6 thumb">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="${url}" alt="${item.name}">
                        </div>
                        <input id="name_${item.id}" type="hidden" value="${item.name}">
                        <input id="name_${item.id}" type="hidden" value="${item.review}">
                    </c:forEach>
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${!empty itemList}">
                    <h1>Nothing found</h1>
                </c:if>
            </div>
```

JS File

```
function filterItems(value) {

    $("#itemListContainer").empty();

        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            //dataType: "json",
            url: "filterItems.htm",
            data: {
                type: value
            },                
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) { 
                    $("#itemListContainer").html(data);                    
                } else {
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                    alert("failure");
                }    
            }, 
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
            }     
        });
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/filterItems", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Item> filterItems(@RequestParam(value = "type", required = false) String type) {
        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        try {
            items = itemDao.getItems(type);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }        
        return items;
    }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please include the relevant stacktrace.

Comment: "The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request". No exception I can see from the eclipse console. I'd gladly paste the catalina.out log entries but i have no idea where to find those in Mac OSX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again, when it comes my little experience with hibernate, the error has nothing to do with Javascript, controller o DAO but with entity mapping.

My Item entity had an association with a User entity, and  had to specify between lazy and eager loading of the association. In my case it was solved by adding `lazy="true"` to my xml file.